# Merging two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 `DataFrames` which I would like to merge. I have looked at the documentation and tried to perform the following operation but an getting confused as to how to do it. Like I said I have 2 `DataFrames`:

```
df1:

      id        name  type currency
0  BTA.S   Applewood  Hard      GBp
1  VOD.S    Softwood  Soft      GBp
```

and

```
df2:

   id
BTA.S    301.221525
VOD.S    213.791400
```

and I would like to return:

```
      id        name  type currency       price
0  BTA.S   Applewood  Hard      GBp  301.221525
1  VOD.S    Softwood  Soft      GBp  213.791400
```

Where the price column from the df2 is merged with df1.  (Just to let you know there will be alot more wood types by the time I've finished).

I have tried a few methods of doing this:

```
Result = df1.merge(df2[['*.S']], left_on='id', right_index=True)
```

where I met the exception:

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

and

```
Result = pd.concat([Df1, Df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

where I get the exception:

```
ValueError: labels ['type'] not contained in axis
```

But I am getting confused.

Answer (score 44):

The error message indicates that `df2` is of type `pd.Series`. You need to convert `df2` `.to_frame()` as `.merge()` needs a `pd.DataFrame()` input ([see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)):

```
df1.merge(df2[['*.S']].to_frame(), left_on='id', right_index=True)
```

while you probably also just could:

```
df1.merge(df2.to_frame(), left_on='id', right_index=True)
```

Alternatively, you can use `pd.DataFrame.join()` which accepts a `pd.Series`.

Comment: One may have to transform the frame to match the column. 

For e.g.
`a1 = [['10', '1.2', '4.2'], ['15', '70', '0.03'], ['8', '5', '0']]`
`a2 = [['10', '1.2', '4.2'], ['1', '0', '0.06'], ['6', '4', '3']]`
`df1 = pd.DataFrame(a1, columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])`
`df2 = pd.DataFrame(a2, columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])`
`pd.merge(df1, df2.loc[0].to_frame().T, on=['one', 'one'], how='inner')`

Answer (score 6):

This error means that one of your objects is **not** a pandas Data Frame.

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

To prove this to yourself,

```
print(type(df2))
```

And that should output `pandas.core.series.Series`

To achieve your desired result,

```
df2 = df2.to_frame().reset_index()
df2.columns = ['id', 'price']
df1.merge(df2)
```

Outputs:

```
    id  name    type    currency    price
0   BTA.S   Applewood   Hard    GBp     301.221525
1   VOD.S   Softwood    Soft    GBp     213.791400
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add df2 (which is a Series, not a DataFrame) as a new column

```
df['price']=df2
```

Answer (score 0):

use to_frame() or updata your pandas;

join Series with Dataframe is accepted in new pandas version