# Faster pandas apply using modin.pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, modin

Trying to use all cores for this apply function using modin.pandas

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
# sentiment Score of essay
data = data.merge(data.essay.apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'neg':sid.polarity_scores(s)['neg'], 
                                                 'neu':sid.polarity_scores(s)['neu'],
                                                 'pos':sid.polarity_scores(s)['pos'],
                                                 'compound':sid.polarity_scores(s)['compound']})), 
           left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

It works with default pandas, but using modin raises this error:

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'modin.pandas.series.Series'>
```

essay is text column in the DataFrame named "data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968785/merging-two-dataframes) suggest, you are likely getting this error because you are merging a `pandas.Dataframe` with a `modin.Series`. For your example, try converting `data` to a modin dataframe with `modin.pandas.DataFrame(data)`.